# Let $a,b\in \mathbb R$. Show if $a\leq c$ for every $c > b$, then $a≤b$.

Tags: inequality, real-numbers

> Let $a,b\in \mathbb R$.  Show if $a≤c$ for every $c > b$, then $a≤b$.

I tried doing a proof by use of the contrapositive, but I can't manage to make it work. If someone could provide some guidance that would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Simple contradiction. Assume $a>b$ and consider $c = \frac{a+b}{2}$.

Now $c=\frac{a+b}{2}>\frac{b+b}{2}=b$, but $c=\frac{a+b}{2}<\frac{a+a}{2}=a$

Comment: How do you reach the conclusion of $c=\frac{a+b}{2}$?

Comment: I simply take middle. It works if you take any point between: for $0<\lambda<1$ we can take $c =\lambda a + (1-\lambda)b $.

Comment: Hey, what is this principle called? I am asking since I saw it in a lot of different math books I'm assuming it has an origin. i would be grateful if you guide me.

Comment: It's equation of interval with ends $a,b$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $a>b$. Choose $\epsilon>0$ small enough such that $c=b+\epsilon<a$. It is a contradiction because $c>b$.